# Display list base on HTTP GET response in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-native-ios

I'm trying to display a list into my view base on the HTTP GET response.

I have

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {

    state = { albums: [] }; 

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => this.setState({albums:response.data}));
    }

    renderAlbums() {
        this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{ album.title }</Text> );
    }

    render() { 
        // console.log(this.state);
        console.log(this.state.albums);

        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderAlbums() }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

I kept getting empty

[image]

But I can't seem to see my response in the console.

## Update

After fix this line

> `return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{ album.title }</Text> );`

I still get this

[image]

> TypeError: this.state.albums.map is not a function
>
> ---

I expected to see something like this

[image]

Comment: I tried your fixed code [here](https://snack.expo.io/SyqNa5MQQ) and it is working. Do you thing you might be missing something?

Comment: I saw it is working in Expo site and app too. I don't know why it is not working on my local ... should I restart something ?

Comment: If it is a `react-native init` project you can try to restart the bundling server. Trying to delete caches might help too. I'm not sure why you are getting error too.

Comment: I think because I don't have the style, like your. ???

Comment: You can try to add

Comment: Add style still not working, something with this line `return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>album.title</Text>);`

Comment: the `map` function works only on an array. Make sure that you are getting an array as a response and the same is getting set in the state.

Answer (score 1):

in `renderAlbums`, you're missing a `return`

```
renderAlbums () {
  return this.state...
}
```

for what it's worth, `componentWillMount` isn't supposed to be used to fetch data (and call `this.setState`) - you should stick that in `componentDidMount`

Comment: I am just following the tutorial right now, but yes, I will take your advise into consideration. :)

Comment: Did you spot anything else ?

Comment: Actually, I had an Action.Loading screen which is pushed when the request is made and popped when the request is successfull, so the animation will not work when it is popped since animation works only once during the screen creation it seems